# Can't run php artisan make in vagrant nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant

I'm creating a development environment using **Vagrant** with this dependencies:

- PHP7;
- Nginx 1.9;
- Laravel 5.3.

The problem is when I try to run `php artisan make:controller Test` I received this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#5 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(71): Illuminat in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#5 /vagrant/v in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
```

## Describing my enviroment

My Laravel project is at the root of `var/www`, and i run the following commands to change folders permissions:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name advodocs.local.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # Customiza propriedades do Vagrant
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2524]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 1]
    end

    # Escolhe a box
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

    # Configura port forwarding
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.20"

    #Inicia o provisionamento
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/init.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/php.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/postgres.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/nginx.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/node.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/git.sh"

    #Muda o dono de algumas pastas
    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant",
    owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www",
    owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

end
```

Obs: Laravel project is at the root of /var/www

Repository link [here](https://bitbucket.org/advodocs/advodocs)

Comment: Check out my answer and please mark as accepted if it solves the issue. If it doesn't, please post the error and I would be happy to help out

Comment: Do you really need a bounty just to read errors? `The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened` means that you should set writing rights to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running an Artisan command to make your controller, the command is trying to create your controller file through your ubuntu user but your ubuntu user doesn't have write permissions to your app folders to create the controller.

Let's say your ubuntu user is allan, do the following to solve this:

1. `chown -R allan:allan /var/www`
2. `chown -R allan:www-data /var/www/storage`
3. `chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage`
4. `chown -R allan:www-data /var/www/bootstrap/cache`
5. `chmod -R 775 /var/www/bootstrap/cache`

Now run your artisan command. It should work. If it doesn't, just check your `/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log` file and post the error

Alternatively, a quick and dirty way (that I don't recommend) is that you can just run your command through your www-data user like so: `sudo su -s /bin/bash www-data` and then run your Artisan command

Answer (score 0):

I've just change my `config.vm.synced_folder` to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant",
    owner: "vagrant", group: "www-data", mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]
```